# How to set XDG_RUNTIME_DIR

Tags: xdg

`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not well set on my computer and this causes `upstart` to write PID files to my home folder. May I know what it should be and where to set it?

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, it is of the form:

```
/run/user/$(id -u)
```

For example, my UID is 1000, so `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is `/run/user/1000`. You can try setting it in `~/.pam_environment`:

```
echo "XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)" >> ~/.pam_environment
```

I couldn't find any sources for this, though.

Answer (score 2):

Set:

```
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
```

To make this permanent, put it into your .bashrc file:

```
echo "export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: To run `~/.bashrc` commands we can also (apart from `source`) re-login if connected remotely via ssh.